# Strings concatenation in XML (build.xml)

Tags: xml, ant, build, string-concatenation

Is there any ways to do strings concatination in a `build.xml file?

Concretely, suppose I have a build file that has this block:

```
  <target name="test1" depends="build">
            <property name ="fname1"/>
            <property name ="fname2"/>
            <echo message=<fname1 CONCAT fname2>/>            
            ...            
    </target>
```

I'd like to concatenate `fname1` and `fname2` .

I tried `<echo message = "${fname1}" + "${fname2}"` but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just do:

```
<echo message="${fname1}${fname2}"/>
```

or

```
<echo>${fname1}${fname2}</echo>
```

Much more information on how properties work in ANT, and particularly how property expansion works can be found in the concepts section in the ant manual: http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple properties in one string. For example:

```
  <target name="test1" >
    <property name="fname1" value="a"/>
    <property name="fname2" value="b"/>
    <echo message="${fname1} CONCAT ${fname2}"/>            
  </target>
```

prints  "`a CONCAT b`"  on the console

Comment: why has this answer been downvoted ??? It's essentially the same as the accepted answer. In fact it's even better as it exactly echoes what was asked for : <fname1 CONCAT fname2>

Comment: @Rebse Because the OP's question makes it obvious that "CONCAT" was a placeholder for the operation he was trying to perform, not the actual desired output.